# Boolean to Color converter in wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, styles

I have a wpf application in which I'd like to convert a color of radio button to (Green/Red) compared to a boolean value :

**In Xaml File**

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
            <local:BooleanToColorConverter  x:Key="ToColorConverter"/>
             </UserControl.Resources>

...........
     <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Statut" Binding="{Binding IsOnline, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <RadioButton Foreground="{Binding IsOnline, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Converter={StaticResource ToColorConverter}}" IsChecked="True"  >  
                                    </RadioButton>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And I added this converter :

```
 public class BooleanToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool blnIsConnected = (bool)value;
            return (blnIsConnected == true) ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
             return (value == Brushes.Green) ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

I get as a result  :

[image]

I get the blue color in all the cases !!

1. What is the problem with my code?
2. How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I tried to edit the radio button template like this

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Statut" Binding="{Binding IsOnline, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton  IsChecked="True"  >
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">

                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                                                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                                                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                                            <Grid Width="13" Height="13">   
                                                                <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark"  Margin="4" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding IsOnline,  UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Converter={StaticResource ToColorConverter}}" />
                                                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                                                </Ellipse>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                                   </BulletDecorator>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                               </Setter.Value>
                                           </Setter> </Style>

                                </RadioButton>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I get the same result

Comment: ToColorConverter should not be BooleanToColorConverter  ?

Comment: Is your converter name Correct?

Comment: @Beatles1692 see my edit plz : I added breakpoints inside the converter class and it is reachable

Comment: The Foreground property is used for the RadioButton text, but not for its check mark. You'll have to modify its Style.

Comment: I think you would need to modify control template of the radio button and change the color of the bullet decorator inside it.

Comment: @Kavish How can I do this?Any suggestions

Comment: Here is the default template [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600.aspx) just change the color of the bullet decorator or the check mark  depending on your requirement.

Comment: Did you override the default style property?

Comment: @Kavish no I did not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should specify `DataContext` for child of your `DataGridTemplateColumn` item. By default it takes parent context (your ViewModel for example). Solution:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
                ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

2) You can draw only `BulletDecorator` withour RadioButton (and final solution is):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <BulletDecorator DataContext="{Binding}">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark"  Margin="4" Visibility="Visible" 
                        Width="10" Height="10" 
                        Fill="{Binding IsOnline, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ToColorConverter}}"></Ellipse>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            </BulletDecorator>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TVWS.png